# Php mailer sending mail but not received

Tags: php

I am using this code. It gives me reply mail sent successfully but the mail not received at the address?

```
function sendmail($to,$subject,$message) {

        $mail = new PHPMailer; // call the class
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.pepipost.com'; //Hostname of the mail server
        $mail->Port = 587; //Port of the SMTP like to be 25, 80, 465 or 587
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; //Whether to use SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'mahadev'; //Username for SMTP authentication any valid email created in your domain
        $mail->Password = 'Arena@123'; //Password for SMTP authentication
        $mail->AddReplyTo("info@pepisandbox.com", "Sudam Wanve"); //reply-to address
        $mail->SetFrom("info@pepisandbox.com", "Sudam SMTP Mailer"); //From address of the mail
        // put your while loop here like below,
        $mail->Subject = "Test MAil"; //Subject od your mail
        $mail->AddAddress("imranq031@gmail.com"); //To address who will receive this email
        $mail->MsgHTML("<b>Hi, your first SMTP mail has been received. Great Job!.. <br/><br/>by <a href='http://asif18.com'>Asif18</a></b>"); //Put your body of the message you can place html code here
       //Attach a file here if any or comment this line,
        $send = $mail->Send(); //Send the mails
        echo $send;
        if($send){
            echo '<center><h3 style="color:#009933;">Mail sent successfully</h3></center>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<center><h3 style="color:#FF3300;">Mail error: </h3></center>'.$mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
}
```

Comment: The mail is probably stuck in the mail system on smtp.pepipost.com. Do you have access to that machine so you could look at the logs and the mail queue?

Comment: Also consider that you mail might get flagged as SPAM, especially since it uses html markup in an invalid way.

Comment: The method only returns `true` if the mail was successfully passed over to the mail server, not if the mail server successfully sent the mail. You should check your mail server logs